# find logFC“,”logCPM“,”PValue“ and ”FDR"

Tags: r

I have 2 files each for one disease. one has 514 replicates and the other one has 164 replicates. the columns represent the expression values for the genes in the first column. i.e, the first column in both is the genes' names and followed by 514 replicates in one disease and by 164 in the other one. I want to find logFC","logCPM","PValue" and "FDR" for the genes between these two diseases. I have merged the two files in one file and the result file contains the genes' list in the first column followed by 678 (514 + 164)for the replicates and I have written the following code:

```html
data <- as.matrix(read.table("input.txt"))
apply(data,2,as.numeric) 
g <- rep(1:2,c(514,164))
libSizes <- as.vector(colSums(data))
d <- DGEList(counts=data,group=g,lib.size=libSizes)
d <- calcNormFactors(d)
d <- estimateCommonDisp(d, verbose=TRUE)
d <- estimateTagwiseDisp(d)
de.com <- exactTest(d)
results <- topTags(de.com,n = length(data[,1]))
write.table(as.matrix(results$table),file="output.txt",sep="\t")
```

The problem is I have to remove the first column and the header of the file because I have to convert the file to numeric and give it to DGEList but I think this affect the result since I have gotten 5 columns. I don't know the extra one for what and which one I have to remove or I have to change something in the code to get the genes' list and "logFC","logCPM","PValue" and "FDR".

A part of the input file as following:

```html
0.653993654 1.276692803 0.556128836 0.775983885 0.717589861 0.527708645 0.166243201 0.553488322 0.609239378 0.692983515 0.471143328 1.272292021 4.046941818 1.261593123 0.562684267 0.711300711 0.740874302 0.655042384
0.554710909 0.829202988 0.700911902 0.52594095 0.641069574 0.637162311 1.220821654 0.687161832 0.485179363 0.740110493 1.841845453 0.831462471 0.612542161 0.419160471 0.590194356 1.516203728 0.44318416 1.067371896
1.169490025 0.193918655 0.809054876 0.739811238 0.607294663 1.736244703 0.669051176 1.614793581 0.896046773 0.854208594 1.048149417 0.811260135
```

A part of the output file is:

```html
"logFC" "logCPM" "PValue" "FDR"
"5162" 5.72927777667766 6.13200524980798 0 0
"21255" 4.97051820458245 6.8104549379198 0 0
"1611" 4.91542796319906 4.07820237328353 0 0
"4240" 4.51370468392384 8.49163867594591 0 0
"6263" 4.41506127922583 4.37500336136578 0 0
"17984" 3.76429054450582 3.91375102721913 0 0
"16911" 3.25334412628318 6.99703369826114 0 0
"1243" 2.25873960411886 7.97612835271848 0 0
"8773" 2.10924898345989 6.89323880133367 0 0
"22493" 1.93358582203404 5.51597962936543 0 0
```

Thank you.